# C# retrieving image in db. Get Error Parameter in not valid

Tags: c#, image

I don't know what's wrong with my code in retrieving image in db. I insert image without using image path file cause the image provide by the cam.

Here's my code in inserting image in db

```
Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
byte[] imageBt = memStream.ToArray();
query = "";
query += "INSERT INTO table(picture) VALUES ('" + imageBt + "')";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.close();
```

Here's my code in retrieving image in db

```
query = "";
query += "SELECT picture FROM table WHERE id = '1'";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] image = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
ms.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
con.Close();
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms)
pictureBox1.Image = bmp; //Still get the Error here parameter is not valid
```

Is there anywrong process in saving image in database. Btw my image type in db is Blob. I don't know why it doesn't work in retrieving image it always thrown error. Thanks

Comment: i also try this one but i doesn't work also
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (dr.Read())
{
    byte[] data = (byte[])dr["picture"];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}

Comment: Looks like you are trying to insert text.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: You should start using SQL parameters immediately.

Comment: How can you append the `byte[] imageBt` variable to a string? `query += "INSERT INTO table(picture) VALUES ('" + imageBt + "')";` I think you want to insert a binary blob or something in hex, but not like this. Check what exact query is executed above, wouldn't wonder if its `".. VALUES (System.Byte[])`

Comment: Any time you have a question about a “thrown error” please include the error message.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question really aprreciated it :)

Answer (score 2):

When reading, you haven't rewound the stream. If you `Write`, you must set `ms.Position = 0;` afterwards. Or simpler: create the stream *from the data*, then you don't need to:

```
byte[] image = ...
var ms = new MemoryStream(image);
```

When writing, you seem to have injected the data directly. That... almost certainly won't work - in fact, you're probably writing `System.Byte[]` to the command. Ideally, use a parameter:

```
query = "INSERT INTO table(picture) VALUES (@blob)";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("blob", imageBt);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(the exact syntax may change between RDBMS implementations)

Comment: Thanks for answering this question really aprreciated it :). 
May i ask if do i need to change the way how i insert image in db? Thanks

Comment: @issei-kun yes; the code in the question doesn't insert the image into the DB.  IIt inserts the string `"System.Byte[]"` every single time. I'm Guessing that isn't what you intended.

Comment: Yeah but how will i insert the image in db and retrieve it. It seems my pic in db when i try to retrieve it always throw error parameter is not valid. How will i fix it or what is the proper way of inserting image in db with blob type and retrieve it in picture box.

Comment: @issei-kun I've already answered these questions. And if you are using the sql shown in your question to insert into the DB: no, your image is not in the DB. The literal string `System.Byte[]` is what you will have stored every time. Not the contents.

Comment: so much better if i will not convert my image into byte[] array? and retrieve it by creating stream?

Comment: @issei-kun I only mentioned stream because `Bitmap` reads from one; at the DB level, you should be talking with `bye[]` each time, as a parameter `.Value` when writing, and as a column value when reading